# Can I pass a DBNull to Integer type variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is this possible to send a DB null to a integer variable.

I'm calling a function

```
private void BindGridView(String Fromdate, String Todate, int IsPending)
```

1. fromdate
2. todate
3. ispending **is my stored procedure scalar variable**

On pageload I show the both detail (ispending or not pending).  For this I need to pass null.

Is there need to change the signature of function?

Comment: why isn't 'IsPending' a bool?

Comment: @Daniel Casserly Bool Support only False or true not null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the int parameter nullable, then check for a value when calling your sproc:

```
private void BindGridView(String Fromdate, String Todate, int? IsPending) {
```

and then

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intParam", 
                 IsPending.HasValue ? (object)IsPending.Value : DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a Nullable Type. In C# you can use the question mark. Instead of Nullable<int> you can write int ?

```
private void BindGridView(String Fromdate, String Todate, int ? IsPending)
```